# get Scrollview inside navigation drawer Programmatically

Tags: android, scrollview, navigation-drawer

i have a navigation drawer base on menu items.i want to get Scrollview inside navigation drawer.

**my navigation drawer**:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
```

**items**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/nav_hesab_karbari"
    app:showAsAction="never" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_wallets"
    android:title="@string/nav_kif">

</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_messages"
    android:title="@string/nav_payamha"/>
```

Comment: `NavigationView` already scrolls on its own.

Comment: @MikeM. i know its scroll on its own.i dont have have problem with scroll.i want to get scrollview Programmatically to do some work on it.any ideas?

Comment: Then I'm not at all clear on what you're asking. There is no `ScrollView` in a `NavigationView`.